# How to merge and then sort two lists in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to print the books of two authors in order of year published.

**Desired output:**

```
[
  {
     name: 'Player Piano',
     published: 1952,
     author: 'Kurt Vonnegut'
  },
  {
     name: 'Lolita',
     published: 1955,
     author: 'Vladimir Nobokov'
  },
  {
     name: 'Cat's Cradle',
     published: 1963,
     author: 'Kurt Vonnegut'
  }
]
```

My query looks like this:

```
MATCH(kbook:Book)<-[:WROTE]-(author:Author { name: 'Kurt Vonnegut' })

MATCH(nbook:Book)<-[:WROTE]-(author:Author { name: 'Vladimir Nobokov' })
WITH kbook, nbook

ORDER BY kbook.published, nbook.published
RETURN collect(kbook) + collect(nbook)
```

**My problem**: if amount of Nobokov's books is less than that of Kurt's books, Nobokov's books will repeat until their amounts are equal (and vice versa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATED]

Here is a simple and efficient query (which only needs a single `MATCH`). For example, if the list of author names is passed in an `authNames` [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/):

```
MATCH (b)<-[:WROTE]-(a:Author)
WHERE a.name IN $authNames
WITH {name: b.title, published: b.published, authors: COLLECT(a.name)} AS item
ORDER BY b.published
RETURN COLLECT(item) AS books
```

`COLLECT(a.name)` is used to make the `authors` value a list, since a book can generally have multiple authors.

You may also want to create an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/) on `Author(name)` to optimize the query.

#### Addendum

If you want to get a date-sorted list of book data (with possibly different properties, from various parts of the DB), you may want to use the new [post-union processing](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/call-subquery/#subquery-post-union) support. For example, if you want to get a sorted list of books either authored by an author in `$authNames` or reviewed by a reviewer in `$revNames`:

```
CALL {
  MATCH (b)<-[:WROTE]-(a:Author)
  WHERE a.name IN $authNames
  RETURN {name: b.title, published: b.published, authors: COLLECT(a.name)} AS item
  UNION ALL
  MATCH (b)<-[:REVIEWED]-(r:Reviewer)
  WHERE r.name IN $revNames
  RETURN {name: b.title, published: b.published, reviewers: COLLECT(r.name)} AS item
}
WITH item.name AS name, apoc.map.mergeList(COLLECT(item)) AS merged
ORDER BY merged.published
RETURN COLLECT(merged) AS books
```

[UNION ALL](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/union/#query-union) is used (instead of `UNION`) to avoid the effort to remove duplicates because in this example the 2 subqueries should not produce duplicate items. More `UNION`s can be added for additional subqueries.

The [apoc.map.mergeList](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/data-structures/map-functions/#map-functions) function is used (along with the [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) `COLLECT`) to merge the author and reviewer data for the same book into a single map.

Comment: this is also a perfectly acceptable answer, I only chose Brant's answer because it would also allow me to merge properties from nodes (or relationships) with different labels.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a suggestion for how to handle that.

Comment: Yes, the post-union processing (if your version supports it) is indeed a better technique.

Answer (score 1):

You can can collect the 1st, collect the 2nd, aggregate the list, unwind return and sort. Try this, modified from this article:
https://neo4j.com/blog/cypher-union-query-using-collect-clause/

```
MATCH (kbook:Book)<-[:WROTE]-(kauthor:Author {name: 'Kurt Vonnegut'})
WITH collect({name: kbook.name, published: kbook.published, author: kauthor.name}) as rows
MATCH(nbook:Book)<-[:WROTE]-(nauthor:Author {name: 'Vladimir Nobokov'})
WITH rows + collect({name: nbook.name, published: nbook.published, author: nauthor.name}) as allRows
UNWIND allRows as row
RETURN row
ORDER BY row.published
```